# В чем разница объявления переменных и функций в классе php?

Tags: php, ооп, классы

```
class Person {
    var $name;
    public $age;
}
```

В чем различие между var и public?

```
class Car {
    function start() {...};
    public function stop() {...};
}
```

В чём различие между function и public function?

Comment: все просто это когда то было для совместимости, сейчас var устарел и объявление без области видимости тоже

Comment: @Naumov то есть теперь у меня на выбор public, private или protected, так? Объявлять переменные через var - устарело, а без ключевых слов (просто $varName) - вообще работать не будет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

что же вы так ленитесь читать [документацию](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.visibility.php)-то?

> В чем разница объявления переменных и функций в классе php?

читаем доки:

> Свойства класса должны быть определены через модификаторы `public`, `private` или `protected`. Если же свойство определено с помощью `var`, то оно будет объявлено общедоступным свойством.

в [дополнение](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.properties.php)

> Для того, чтобы поддерживать обратную совместимость с PHP 4, PHP 5 по-прежнему позволяет использовать ключевое слово var при определении свойств вместо (или в дополнении к) public, protected, или private. Однако var больше не требуется. В версиях PHP с 5.0 по 5.1.3 использование var считалось устаревшим и выдавало предупреждение E_STRICT, но с PHP 5.1.3 больше не считается устаревшим и не выдает предупреждения.
>   Если вы объявляете свойство с помощью var вместо public, protected или private, тогда PHP 5 будет рассматривать свойство так, как если оно было объявлено как public.

второй вопрос:

> В чём различие между function и public function?

читаем доки:

> Методы класса должны быть определены через модификаторы `public`, `private`, или `protected`. Методы, где определение модификатора отсутствует, определяются как `public`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. но что я должен был искать в гугле, что-бы найти это?) Я искал: Разниица var и public, ответа не получил, пришел на стак.

Comment: @ArtyomZinovyev при чем тут гугл? надо было открыть документацию по пхп и посмотреть соответствующий раздел. ссылка на него в ответе приведена. просто надо было прочитать доки про объявление свойств и область видимости полей/методов

Comment: Я перед каждым вопросом на стаковерфлоу проверяю: точно ли я не могу сам найти ответ? Я учусь (в неспешном темпе) уже год, и только сейчас узнал про классы. Вообще не понимал, что в документации php делают такие слова как `public`, `class`, почему там переменные иногда объявляются через `var`, а не просто со знаком `$`. Когда я задавал этот вопрос, я параллельно тестировал всё в онлайн компиляторе. Создавал экземпляры класса, узнал про то, как использовать `static`, а после вашего ответа мне еще и стало ясно, зачем нужно `var` в php. Спасибо.